# LifecycleObserver - Check if observer has another owner

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, android-livedata

I have a class which I attached an observer to in the constructor:

```
public class MyStateMgr implements LifecycleObserver {

     public MyStateMgr (LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
            lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get IllegalArgumentException. I checked about this crash and I saw that "If the observer is already in the list with another owner, LiveData throws an IllegalArgumentException."

I call this constructor only once.
How can I check if this observer has another owner? Is there a way to check it? Maybe it's another reason?

This is the crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
       at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.downEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:255)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.backwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:306)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:327)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: you can check it with `hasActiveObservers()` method : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#hasActiveObservers()

Comment: Thanks but it only works on a livedata object and I don't have it here, I have observer on "lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle()".

Comment: Are you using `LifeCycleObserver` ? In that case, You should check if `LiveData` has active observers in Your LifeCycleOwner. and then if you don't have any then try to observe on it again. Share some code so that i can show you how to.

Comment: Yes, I'm using LifecycleObserver (I'll edit my post), and what I wrote in the post is the only relevant code...

Comment: What if you remove your observer manually using `lifecycle.removeObserver()`? Check if this solve the exception. call this on destroy method of your lifecycle owner.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Ok, thanks, I'll try it.